# Как сделать menuitem неактивным?

Tags: gwt, java

В GWT есть баг, что пункт меню в `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuBar` нельзя сделать `disabled`. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использую свойство элемента - opacity. Самый простой способ - дописать свой метод setEnabled:

```
private boolean enabled = true;

public void setEnabled(boolean value) {
   getElement.getStyle.setOpacity(value? 1.0 : 0.5);
   enabled = value;
}

public void execute() {
  if (enabled) {
     // ... 
  }
}
```